# Is there any Private API that can change all system Font in IOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, iphone-privateapi

I want to know is there any `Font Private API` or Framework that can change or replace font for all entire iOS systems font like safari , mail etc...?

It's fine for review because i am not upload to App Store.

I just want to use only myself.

Comment: There is a probably some settings file available on disk... You could also replace the font files directly.

Comment: where is it place bro?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but you could create a category for `UIFont` and replace the `+systemFontOfSize:` method implementation (and maybe the one for `bold` and `italic` as well).
Most controls should be using these methods.

Edit: tested, seems to work well. Just make sure to replace the methods for `bold` and `italic` as well.

```
@interface UIFont(Extra)

@end

@implementation UIFont(Extra)

+(UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Amelie" size:size];  // note that "Amelie" is a custom font, doesn't come by default with iOS.
}
+(UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Amelie" size:size];
}
@end
```

Comment: that can replace or change entire system font bro? And how to use it? :D

Comment: Well, you could try it, there's only a few lines of code. Standard controls use these methods. If however you have custom controls that explicitly call `[UIFont fontWithName:@"x" size:y]`, than the `x` font will be used for those controls (you could also replace `-fontWithName:size:` if this is a problem).

Comment: yes , i tried with your code and it doesn't change at all bro. my app is also running in background and i tried with safari browser in my simulator , it doesn't change. How can i do that?

Comment: I thinks you and i are misunderstanding. i mean i want to change all entire system font like safari , mail etc with Private API. :D

Comment: Oh, I see.. I thought you want to change it for your app only.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. You do not have access to any other app / system code from your app. This is definitely not possible from Xcode and at the very least would require the device to be jailbroken.